# How to change pixels position in image python

Tags: image, python-2.7, pixel

I'm trying to read an image and to change pixels positions like (x-a), and (y-yb) in python. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you have in mind saying about changing pixel position?

Comment: I want to mesh up image with certain function.

Comment: This does not answer my question. As I understand your question now you have to learn the concept of loops.

Comment: I want to read image as [x,y,(r,g,b)] and to get another one with [x-a,y-b, (r,g,b)] where x and y are coordinates